# Hand writing recognition

Tags: handwriting-recognition

I need to make an internal application for personal use where i can write with pen on paper, and it can be stored digitally.
This must have minimal hardware requirement, to avoid extra cost.
What are the services and devices available for building such application.
Introduction of tablets, mobile, touch screen devices will overshoot the cost.
How this can be implemented in cost effected way.

Comment: This will probably be seen as too broad. I suggest finding a handwriting-recognition library, attempting to make it work, and then post specific questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming platform and language agnosticism:

**Hardware:** [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) provides an open-source, bare-bones, inexpensive solution in the $5-30 (USD) range. You would, however, need to purchase appropriate peripherals on an as-needed basis (e.g., camera, enclosure, power-source, etc).

**Software:** The Python programming language features a wealth of robust libraries that would help you accomplish such a computer vision application without having to bother learning the nuts and bolts of computer vision algorithms. I recommend searching the Stack Exchange for inquiries into the applicability for OpenCV toward handwriting recognition. Here are some resources to get you started:

1. [OpenCV Documentation](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_knn/py_knn_opencv/py_knn_opencv.html)
2. [A research paper exploring the idea in depth](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/vincent.neiger/publications/report_digit_recognition.pdf)
3. [Video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Uf_ISEScWM)
4. [Another academic paper](https://cs.earlham.edu/~twright09/paper.pdf)

Remember, there might be many ways to get the job done. Each approach carries merits and faults in terms of performance and practicality, and the question is likely still an area of very active research (machine learning, neural networks). My suggestion is that you weigh your priorities carefully and proceed accordingly (i.e., value learning experience or getting the job done?). I'll try to tag the question that might attract more seasoned, precise answers for software implementation.